# UICollectionView Remove Spacing

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

In interface builder, I set all the spacing to 0 (both line and between cells), but it's still showing some spacing between cells. How do I fix this so cells are touching each other and there is no white space?

Comment: Are the cells fixed width / are you setting a fixed number of cells in the visible area?

Comment: the cells are fixed width, yes

Comment: Please post screen shot of output.

Comment: If the cells are fixed width, is it possible that they are being evenly distributed within the container space, creating spacing between them?